# Get the fields from a reference entity (content type) in a Paragraph field

Tags: theming, 8, entities, paragraphs

I have a paragraph field that is a reference entity to the *Customer Testimonial* content type. A content editor can add the *customer-testimonial* paragraph and type the name of the testimonial. This will then display the text on the website.

I have made a *paragraph--c15a-customer-testimonial.html.twig* template file with the following code.

```
{%
  set c15a = {

    title: content.field_testimonial.entity.field_testimonial_titel,

  }
%}

<div class="component c15a">
    <div>

        <div>Testimonial title</div>

        <h2>{{ c15a.title }}</h2>

    </div>
</div>
```

Of course, this prints nothing. How can I get the fields from the content type I'm referencing in my paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referenced entity is not built yet, so you can't access the formatted field content.

You can get the field value from the database by using the paragraph object:

```
{{ paragraph.field_testimonial.entity.field_testimonial_titel.value }}
```

This is unformatted, which might work for a title field.

If you want a formatted output better use a custom view mode for the referenced entity to configure the fields, or in this case one field, if this is all you want to display.

Comment: Your proposed path to get the value is not working, but this is: content.field_testimonial[0]['#node'].field_testimonial_titel.value ... why is that?

Comment: yes, this is the same node: `paragraph.field_ref.entity` == `content.field_ref[0]['#node']`. I would use the first one, because this also works if the field is not configured.

Comment: Ok, it does work, i just forgot to replace content. with paragraph. ... thx...